# Running a loop (x) times

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x

I am trying to loop an input for a selected amount of time "enter how may ingredients you want:"  say if the user inputs 5 then a loop "ingredients" will run 5 times for them to enter their ingredients. Sorry if it seems like a basic question, but I'm quite new to this. Thanks for any answers :).

```
a=input("hello, welcome to the recipe calculator \nenter your recipe name, number of      people you will serve and the list of ingredients \n1.retrive recipe \n2.make recipe \noption:")

if a=="2":
    print("now enter the name of your recipe")
    f=open('c:\\username_and_password.txt', 'w')
    stuff = input("create name:")
    nextstuff = (int(input("enter number of people:")))
    nextstufff = (int(input("enter how many ingredients you want:"))) 
    for (nextstufff) in range(0, 10): #I have put 0, 10 because the user probably wont put more than 10 ingredients. But there's probably a much better way?
        print ("ingredient") + (nextstufff) #what am I doing wrong in this for loop

    nextstuffff = (int(input("so how much of\n" + nextstufff + "would you like:")))
    f.write(str(stuff + "\n") + str(nextstuff) + str(nextstufff))
    f.close()
```

Comment: Just a heads up, `nextstuff`, `nextstufff`, and `nextstuffff` aren't particularly easy to distinguish...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be difficult to cleanly answer your question(s) -- so I'll focus specifically on the looping over ingredients question. This should get you pointed in the right direction.

```
def read_items(prompt):
    items = []
    while True:
        answer = raw_input('%s (blank to end): ' % prompt)
        if not answer:
            return items
        items.append(answer)

ingredients = read_items('enter ingredients')
counts = []
for item in ingredients:
    cnt = raw_input('how much of %s:' % item)
    counts.append(int(cnt))

print zip(ingredients, counts)
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not `print ("ingredient") + (nextstufff)`, change it to `print ("ingredient:", nextstufff)`.

Or you can use string formatting:

```
print ("ingredient: %d"%nextstufff)
```